# How do I make music sync with iOS 5 in Ubuntu 11.10 work?

Tags: ipad

I've tried several tutorials on the internet but nothing works. This is not a duplicate, it is true that there are several of them about ios5 but not one of them asks specifically about music syncing or ubuntu oneiric ocelot. My iPod classic syncs just fine with Banshee but my iPad 2 won't. I looked around and saw that an unstable `libimobiledevice-1.1.2` was available, but I can't manage to install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is just no accepted to this solution at the moment. All we can hope for is that an iOS update makes it easier for libimobiledevice to mount our iDevices or for an update to libimobiledevice.

Not the most helpful of answers, I know, but at the moment that's all there is I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Install Oracle's version of Virtual box

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

Install Oracles Extension Pack

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Add your computer user to the vbox group

[VirtualBox doesn't recognize USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140081/virtualbox-doesnt-recognize-usb)

Then download and run a free version of Windows in Virtual Box

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575

You will also need to install wine and winrar to be able to extract these rar files.

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

then download and install winrar

http://www.win-rar.com/start.html?&L=0

extract the virtualbox image and setup virtualbox to run windows

Once windows has started , install guest additions

http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/virtualbox-guest-addons.html

Restart vbox
Now plugin your iOS device and enable it to use USB by clicking on the bottom right corner. Just select your device.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=3696606&postcount=8

Follow these instructions to get the music files off the device

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSanDZuqxoY

To then get the files onto your linux box, just enable filesharing and setup to share your music folder, copy past.