# virtualbox guest not recognising usb

Tags: usb, virtualbox

I am using **fedora as host** and **ubuntu as guest** in my virtualbox.

I followed this link [How to set up USB for Virtualbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox) completely.

But no result.

I updated to latest version in virtualbox,changed my usb device but again I am getting same problem(`no usb connected`).

Is there any other solution to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Add you as a **vboxusers** user. You have to be in the **vboxusers** group.

```
sudo adduser $USER vboxusers
```

To verify it:

```
$ groups
yourUserName : yourUserName adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin scanner sambashare vboxusers
```

If this still doesn't work, Log out and log back in.

Comment: everything in this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/140081/virtualbox-doesnt-recognize-usb working with windows host but not with linux (fedora).still not resolved.

Comment: need to check .. will update you